# How to mixdown surround sound in real time

Tags: sound, headphones

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.1 LTS.

As usual, when I use the *speaker-test -c 8 -l 1 -t sine -f 440* line command, I can clearly hear the 8 audio channels, from the computer sound car, through my stereo headphones. But, it is absolutely noticeable the low level in the side and rear audio channels.

I wonder if there is some way to mixdown all the 8 surround audio channels into just 2 stereo channels, in real time.

The mixdown should be:

Left Front, Left Side and Left Rear ----------> Stereo Left.

Right Front, Right Side and Right Rear ---> Stereo Right.

Center and LFE --------------------------------------> Stereo Left and Right.

Is it possible? How?